# How to force blackberry applications to work over wifi?

Tags: blackberry

While using blackberry applications (which work over internet), the device (BB Torch) is connected to Wifi instead of network provider. The application is not able to access internet however the device is connected to Wifi.

Previously, I was using Aerize Wifix software to force the application to work over Wifi. But now the software is not working on my device.

Is there any other alternate!

And if somebody knows the reason behind it, please reply.

Comment: try this ? if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
     && RadioInfo
       .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
    httpURL += ";interface=wifi";
   }

Comment: If you use `ConnectionFactory` object, you can set preferred transport types (e.g. `TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, `) and priority when attempting to get a connection via `setPreferredTransportTypes`. See the example here, http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Opening_a_network_connection_Network_API_1226178_11.jsp.

Comment: Thanks Signare, it works for me now. Thank you Rupak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) && RadioInfo .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) { httpURL += ";interface=wifi"; }
```

This line of code works for me.

Thanks Signare.